# Is .trim() valid for innerText?

Tags: javascript

This is failing. Is my use of `trim` valid? The span is inside a table row.

```
 var x = document.getElementById('myRow');
 var r = x.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerText;

 if(r.trim() == ""){
   alert("on if")
 }
```

HTML

```
<tr id="header"> 
   <td><span>The Header</span></td>
</tr>
<tr id="myRow">
 <td><span>Sample</span></td>
 <td><span></span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: You are not getting an element with your  `document.getElementById('myRow');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code works if coupled with the correct html

**Sample HTMl:**

```
<table>
    <tr id="header"> 
       <td><span>The Header</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="myRow">
        <td><span>Sample</span></td>
        <td><span></span></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/vfhogegd/4/

**Note**

> Arrays start at index 0

Did you mean to refer to the first span? if so you need to use `[0]` instead of `[1]`

**UPDATE**

Based on your HTML, the issue is that you don't have `<table>` tags...

If you look at your console you will probably see the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

If you do not have `<table>` tags around your `<td>` tags, it is invalid html, most browser will ignore your tags which is why your `getElementByID` isn't returning anything causing the rest of your function to fail

Comment: the span is inside a table.

Comment: doesn't matter what type of tag it is if it has that id

Answer (score 1):

`trim()` can be invoked on any string, including `innerText` since it returns a string.

The code you have provided could be failing for a few different reasons.  You would have to ensure that `document.getElementById('myRow')` actually returns an element, and that `x.getElementsByTagName('span')` also returns at least two elements, since you are attempting to get the `innerText` of the second element returned in that array by specifying an index of 1.

Comment: as Seth mentioned above, you need to wrap your table rows with `<table> </table>` tags.